# jxBrowser and Google maps in Java Swing

Tags: javascript, java, swing, jxbrowser

I'm developing a map with `jxBrowser` in Java Swing, The problem is that I need to return the lat / long variable from javaScript (executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue) to java Swing.

```
  browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(
                "map.addListener('click', function(e) {\n" +
                "placeMarker(e.latLng, map);\n" +
                "});\n" +
                "\n" +
                "function placeMarker(position, map) {\n" +
                "        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({\n" +
                "        position: position,\n" +
                "        map: map,\n" +  
                "        title:'test point',\n " +
                "    });\n" +
                "    map.panTo(position);\n" +
                "}");
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the code that you have posted, the `executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue()` configures a listener to the map events. In this case, you need to call back to the Java side and pass the `latLng` value as soon as the map event is received.

Here is a complete sample demonstrating the approach:

```
public class GoogleMapsSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Browser browser = new Browser();
        browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
                browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window").asObject().setProperty("java", new JavaCallback());
            }
        });
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Provide the correct full path to the map.html file, e.g. D:\\map.html
        Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(Browser value) {
                browser.loadURL("map.html");
            }
        });
        browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(
                "map.addListener('click', function(e) {\n" +
                        "placeMarker(e.latLng, map);\n" +
                        "});\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "function placeMarker(position, map) {\n" +
                        "        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({\n" +
                        "        position: position,\n" +
                        "        map: map,\n" +
                        "        title:'test point',\n " +
                        "    });\n" +
                        "    map.panTo(position);\n" +
                        "    window.java.onMarkerAdded(position);" +
                        "}");
    }

    public static class JavaCallback {
        public void onMarkerAdded(JSObject position){
            double lat = position.getProperty("lat").asFunction().invoke(position).asNumber().getDouble();
            double lng = position.getProperty("lng").asFunction().invoke(position).asNumber().getDouble();
            System.out.println("lat = " + lat + ", lng = " + lng);
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML code of the `map.html` that can be used with this sample:

```
The code of our map.html file is the following:
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
   <style type="text/css">
       html { height: 100% }
       body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
       #map-canvas { height: 100% }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript"
           src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var map;
     function initialize() {
       var mapOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.209331, 16.381302),
         zoom: 4
       };
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To use this file replace API_KEY with your Google API key. See the [instruction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) about how to obtain API key.

You can find the general description of calling back from JavaScript to Java in the following article:
https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013062-calling-java-from-javascript